# View Page label not refreshing with MVVM command in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a page in an e-commerce app for the cart. I have my orders total price as a normal label on the xamarin view page outside of the data template in the xaml code as shown below. I have a button on the viewmodel page which handles the delete command of the products from the cart. I want the total order and the points label to update when a item is deleted from the cart.

Here is my code that I'm using

XAML

```
`<Button ImageSource="bin.png"
                                        x:Name="btnDelete"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference cartCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.CartsCommand}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        Clicked="btnDelete_Clicked"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Order #:"
               FontSize="20"
               TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label x:Name="txtOrderNumber"
              FontSize="20" 
               TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Total Woof Bits earned:" FontSize="Title" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label x:Name="txtPoints" Text="{Binding strPoints}" FontSize="Title" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Total Order:" FontSize="Title" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label  x:Name="txtTotalOrder" Text="{Binding strTotalOrder}" FontSize="Title" TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>`
```

View

```
`public CartPage(CartViewModel viewModels)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModels;
        BindingContext = new CartViewModel();
        ((CartViewModel)BindingContext).LoadCartsCommand.Execute(null);
        ((CartViewModel)BindingContext).LoadTotalsCommand.Execute(null);

        txtOrderNumber.Text = SigninPage.strOrderNumber;
        txtPoints.Text = CartViewModel.strPoints;
        txtTotalOrder.Text = CartViewModel.strTotalOrder;
        
        
    }

    

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();


        ((CartViewModel)BindingContext).LoadCartsCommand.Execute(null);
        ((CartViewModel)BindingContext).LoadTotalsCommand.Execute(null);
        txtPoints.Text = CartViewModel.strPoints;
        txtTotalOrder.Text = CartViewModel.strTotalOrder;
        
    }
    
    


    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        ((CartViewModel)BindingContext).PayCommand.Execute(null);
        
    }

    private void btnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((CartViewModel)BindingContext).LoadTotalsCommand.Execute(null);

        txtPoints.Text = CartViewModel.strPoints;
        txtTotalOrder.Text = CartViewModel.strTotalOrder;
        DisplayAlert("Successful", "Item removed from Cart (▼´•̥ᴥ•̥`) ", "OK");
    }`
```

ViewModel

```
`private ICommand _loadTotalsCommand;


    public ICommand LoadTotalsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loadTotalsCommand == null)
            {
                _loadTotalsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadTotals());
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

            return _loadTotalsCommand;
        }
    }

    public async Task LoadTotals()
    {
        string sqlstring = "MySQL string";
        MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(sqlstring);
        MySqlCommand mysqlcom;
        MySqlDataReader mdr;

        mysqlcon.Open();

        string selectquery = "SELECT ordernumber, quantity, price, sum(price * quantity) AS Total, sum(pointvalue) AS Total1 FROM cart WHERE ordernumber = '" + SigninPage.strOrderNumber + "' GROUP BY ordernumber;";
        mysqlcom = new MySqlCommand(selectquery, mysqlcon);

        mdr = mysqlcom.ExecuteReader();

        while (mdr.Read())
            if (mdr.FieldCount >= 1)
            {
                TotalOrder = mdr.GetDecimal(3);
                Points = mdr.GetDecimal(4);
            }



        mysqlcon.Close();
        strTotalOrder = "R" + Convert.ToString(TotalOrder);
        strPoints = "" + Convert.ToString(Points);

    }



    private ICommand _cartCommand;

    public ICommand CartsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cartCommand == null)
            {
                _cartCommand = new Command<Cart>(async (cart) =>
                {
                    await OnCartSelected(cart);
                });
            }

            return _cartCommand;
        }
    }

    



    public async Task OnCartSelected(Cart cart)
    {


        // Navigate to the ProductDetailsPage and pass the selected product as a parameter
        string constring5 = "MySQL string";
        MySqlConnection con5 = new MySqlConnection(constring5);
        con5.Open();
        MySqlTransaction transaction5 = con5.BeginTransaction();

        using (MySqlCommand cmd5 = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM cart WHERE ordernumber = '" + strOrderNumber4 + "'", con5))
        {
            cmd5.Transaction = transaction5;

            cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction5.Commit();
            con5.Close();
        }

       
        LoadTotalsCommand.Execute(null);
        LoadCartsCommand.Execute(null);
        


    }`
```

Comment: I haven't seen text property for label  in ViewModel. Have you raised property changed for each property?

Comment: And my suggestion is better not use both Clicked Event and Command for a button.

Comment: The reason I use the button Clicked event is because I dont know how to access the label in the mvvm page. i tried binding it and that didnt work it just displayed as blank im assuming its because its not in the datatemplate

Comment: Of course, you can bind the text property of  label in ViewModel.  ```<Label x:Name="txtPoints" Text="{Binding strPoints}"```  You use this in xaml, right?  So  have you set the corresponding property in ViewModel?

Comment: And you set         ```BindingContext = viewModels;BindingContext = new CartViewModel();``` twice

Comment: I havent set the corresponding property in Viewmodel what would the corresponding property be? I'm new to the mvvm architecture.

Comment: To be more clear, i just made an answer below. If you still have any questions, feel free to ask me

Comment: Also you could refer to [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I made the answer below the final conclusion thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a conclusion,

**1**.  Use a proper mvvm way. You may refer to [From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm). Bind to a property in ViewModel and raise PropertyChanged event :

```
    private string _strPoints;
    public string strPoints
    {
        get
        {
            return _strPoints;
        }
        set
        {
            _strPoints = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(strPoints)));
        }
    }
```

When `strPoints` value changed, the UI would refresh.

**2**.   For TabbedPage passing arguments into constructor, you may refer to this: [Passing Arguments in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments)

```
<NavigationPage Title="Cart" IconImageSource="cart.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:CartPage Title="Cart">
            <x:Arguments>
                <viewModels:CartViewModel/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </local:CartPage>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

That generate a **CartViewModel** instance and pass it to the Constructor.

So for **CartPage.cs**, don't have to create any new **CartViewModel** instance any more.

```
    CartViewModel ViewModel;

    public CartPage(CartViewModel viewModels)
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        BindingContext = viewModels;           
        ViewModel = viewModels;
    }
```

**3**.   A way to change the color of RadioButton for Android is to use [**Custom Renderer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

**Step1**.Create your own custom RadioButton in shared project:

```
public class MyRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public MyRadioButton()
    {
    }
}
```

**Step2**.Then in YourProject.Android folder create MyRadioButtonRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyRadioButton), typeof(MyRadioButtonRenderer))]
namespace ViewPageLabelNotRefreshing76512008.Droid
{
    public class MyRadioButtonRenderer : RadioButtonRenderer
    {
        public MyRadioButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<RadioButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.ButtonTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ForestGreen);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step3**.Consume it in xaml,

```
<local:MyRadioButton x:Name="Delivery" Content="Delivery" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>
```

Hope it helps!